# Send Data from Dash Plotly Table to a python Function

Tags: python, html, flask, plotly-dash

I am trying to build an interactive dashboard with Dash Plotly. I created a table where a user can insert address, chain_id, and the API-key. I want to pass those first save them to the table then pass them to a function.

I also created charts for each address, and I want to save the old charts once a user updates the address and a new chart gets produced.

here is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import datetime
import requests

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

    app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

def track(chain_id,address,api_key):
   

    return response



df=response['item']

fig = px.pie(df, values='close.quote', names='contract_name', title='Asset Allocation', color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=12, uniformtext_mode='hide')

fig2=px.line(df_nested, x="timestamp", y="close.quote", color="contract_name",
              line_group="contract_ticker_symbol",labels={
                    "contract_name":'Contract Name',
                    "timestamp": "Date",
                     "close.quote": "USD Value",
                     "contract_ticker_symbol": "Ticker"
                 }, title='Asset Value Over Time', hover_name="contract_ticker_symbol",color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)


app.layout = html.Div([

    


    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='adding-rows-table',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} 
                 for i in ['Wallet Address','Chain ID','Your API-Key']],
        data=[
      
        ],
        style_cell=dict(textAlign='left'),
        # style_header=dict(backgroundColor="paleturquoise"),
        # style_data=dict(backgroundColor="lavender"),
        editable=True,
        row_deletable=True
    ),

    html.Button('Add Wallet', id='editing-rows-button', n_clicks=0),

     dcc.Graph(
            id='graph1',
            figure=fig
        ),  

    dcc.Graph(
            id='graph2',
            figure=fig2
        ),  
])




html.Div(children=[
    # All elements from the top of the page
    html.Div([
        


        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph1',
            figure=fig
        ),  
    ]),
    # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
    html.Div([
       


        dcc.Graph(
            id='graph2',
            figure=fig2
        ),  
    ]),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    Input('editing-rows-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('adding-rows-table', 'data'),
    State('adding-rows-table', 'columns'))
def add_row(n_clicks, rows, columns):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        rows.append({c['id']: '' for c in columns})
    return rows





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So my question is: How do I automatically pass those values(chain_id, address,api_key) in the table to a function and save the charts that are produced for each address? I would really appreciate any guidance!

Comment: what is `external_stylesheets`? Where do you import `dash`? Create minimal working code which we could copy and run for tests and modifications. And you could add some example data directly in code.

Comment: did you try to do it directly in `add_row`?

Comment: I tried but failed to do so, what approach do you recommend?